# Append date to table name and create data frame iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandasql

My goal is to query data from redshift view where the view name is appended by monthdt like view_name_202009 and to query this view month by month for 13 months back, create dataframe and perform transformation. After the first dataframe(**df1)** is created the previous months transformed data should be appended to **df1**.

As a step by step approach:

1. Query current month dataframe
2. create dataframe (df1)
3. Perform transformation
4. Date decrement to previous month (repeat until 13 months back)

Below is the function I wrote to create the sql statements for 13months but I'm failing on passing them to the read_sql squetnailly and create dataframe.

```
def last_n_months(num_of_months, start_date=datetime.now(), include_curr=True):
    f = "%Y%m"
    curr = datetime.now()
    if include_curr:
        yield curr.strftime(f)
    for num in range(num_of_months):
        curr = curr.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
        sql = """select col1, col2,
                 from schema.view_name"""+str(curr.strftime(f))+"""  where col1 in ('01','02','1ST','2ND')"""
        # df = pd.read_sql(sql, con)            
        yield sql

m_lst = [sql for sql in last_n_months(13, include_curr=False)]


df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in m_lst:
    df = df.append(pd.read_sql(m_lst, con))
```

I printed out the m_lst and it looks like below:

```
["select col1, col2 from schema.view_name_202010 where col1 in ('01','02','1ST','2ND')",["select col1, col2 from schema.view_name_202009 where col1 in ('01','02','1ST','2ND')",["select col1, col2 from schema.view_name_202008 where col1 in ('01','02','1ST','2ND')"]
```

I am getting an error as below:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql : argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got list instead
```

Can anyone help me where I'm doing wrong and if there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code bellow

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in m_lst:
    df = df.append(pd.read_sql(i, con))
```

Comment: But that will only pass the first item in the list. What about the remaining 12?

Comment: My bad, I thought you had only one item in your list, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I changed the answer, just delete what I said before and change this